# How to get the 10th highest cost in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I have a table products and i have column `standard_cost` and I want to get the standard cost of the product which lies in 10th highest position. So far I tried

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM (SELECT  STANDARD_COST 
      FROM OT.PRODUCTS 
      ORDER BY STANDARD_COST DESC) t1  
WHERE ROWNUM=1 
ORDER BY t1.STANDARD_COST ASC;
```

But it's giving me the same value when I first sorted descending of inner query and then ascending in ORACLE. What is the problem in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any ways to find nth highest cost.

```
SELECT T1.STANDARD_COST
FROM (
    SELECT STANDARD_COST, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY STANDARD_COST DESC) nth_highest_cost 
    FROM PRODUCTS
) T1
WHERE nth_highest_cost = 10;
```

You can look for other methods from following reference:

- [Different ways to nth Highest in Oracle](http://oraclemine.com/find-nth-highest-salary/)

Comment: I got error like this: [Error] Execution (5: 13): ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Let me check on this, did you tried with table alias too. I have added `T1`

Comment: it again showed me the same error near *,DENSE_RANK()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth_value` analytical function.

```
Select * from
(select t.*, DISTINCT NTH_VALUE(t.standard_cost,10)
       OVER (ORDER BY t.standard_cost desc
       RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
       AS TENTH_HIGHEST
FROM PRODUCTS t)
Where standard_cost = tenth_highest;
```

Cheers!!